# How can I implement Dialog Boxes in XNA

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xna, messagebox

How can I implement something like a dialog box in a XNA game? What I want to do is when the dialog box's image is still active, anything below it will stop receiving user input until the box disappears. Using rectangle's Contains() method doesn't seem to work since it's coordinate based.

For example: clicking on an item will pop up a small "Use" box. Even if that box's image is at the same location (or more accurately, on top of) as another item's, clicking there will only trigger the usage of the first item and not display another "Use" box for the second item, effectively disable the second item's input region in the collision rectangle.

Comment: you already have the answer, just use some flag variables according to which you will control which button gets clicked. If you know how to design menus/interfaces in XNA, this should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some flags to get input

For example,

```
bool accessFlag = true;
```

Then in Update() method

```
if (accessFlag)
{
  // Take input from user
}
```

Then make accessFlag to false when your dialogue box or any other stuff you want, appears. And make it true when pop up disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use UIElementRenderer, as this example shows: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2011/10/26/windows-phone-combining-silverlight-amp-xna-in-a-single-page.aspx

Comment: Is there any way to do that without adding silverlight stuff to my game?

Comment: Sure, you can do it in pure XNA, but it's way easier using UIElementRenderer, since you can define the GUI elements in XAML and create all sorts of fancy animations, states etc.